# Reording array by index of first key?

Tags: php, arrays, search

I would like to reorder my element index aligned array so that I can get elements per unique `CATEGORY` rather than manually by index.

#### Pre-condition

```php
$products = array(
    'CATEGORY' =>
    array(
        0 => 'book',
        1 => 'book',
        2 => 'desk',
    ),
    /* FYI: Other keys have been removed for conciseness */
    'DESCRIPTION' => 
    array(
        0 => 'Bar',
        1 => 'sdfadasfdasfas',
        2 => 'Barrrr',
    ),
);
```

#### Post-condition

```php
$products = array(
    'CATEGORY' =>
    array(
        'book' =>
        array(
            0 =>
            array(
                'DESCRIPTION' => 'Bar',
            ),
            1 =>
            array(
                'DESCRIPTION' => 'sdfadasfdasfas',
            ),
        ),
        'desk' =>
        array(
            0 =>
            array(
                'DESCRIPTION' => 'Barrrr',
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

#### Attempt

```
$cat_to_index = '';

foreach (array_values(array_unique($products['CATEGORY'])) as $category => $uniq_cat) {
    for($i=array_search($uniq_cat, $products['CATEGORY']);
        $i!==FALSE; $i=array_search($uniq_cat, $products['CATEGORY']))
            $cat_to_index .= $i; // just for debugging
}
```

See running on [codepad](http://codepad.org/J6XSraLH).

#### Error

Out of memory (infinite loop). Preferably looking for an `O(n)` solution to this problem.

Comment: Also I don't see why this couldn't be done in `O(n)` where `n` is the size of `$products`...

Comment: On my phone so I only skimmed this over: how about using array_keys then array_count_values?

Comment: `for ($i = array_search(...))` - Just randomly throwing syntax together usually doesn't work... :P

Comment: Throwing random syntax around works in C++ and Python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$products = array(
    'CATEGORY' =>
    array(
        0 => 'book',
        1 => 'book',
        2 => 'desk',
    ),
    /* FYI: Other keys have been removed for conciseness */
    'DESCRIPTION' => 
    array(
        0 => 'Bar',
        1 => 'sdfadasfdasfas',
        2 => 'Barrrr',
    ),
);

$newProducts = array();
$newProducts['CATEGORY'] = array();
foreach ($products['CATEGORY'] as $id =>$cat) {
    $newProducts['CATEGORY'][$cat] []= array('DESCRIPTION' => $products['DESCRIPTION'][$id]);
}

var_dump($newProducts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-keys.php) function can help with the **$search_value** param. I hope this is what you want :

```
<?php
$catalogue_html = '';

// $unique_cats just contains the unique category names

foreach ($uniq_cats as $category => $uniq_cat) {
    // Using the SEARCH param of the "array_key" function
    $keys = array_keys( $products['CATEGORY'] , $uni_cat );
    
    if ( 0 < count( $keys ) ) {
        // Occur more than once
        $catalogue_html .= join(", ", $keys) . "\n";
    }
}

echo $catalogue_html;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not giving me what I want. How do I get [your output](http://codepad.org/O25ObTlc) to be nested arrays instead? - I need to be able to create a new array with `CATEGORY` at top level...

Comment: I don't know you want. But if your are looking for unique $key where to find `CATEGORY` the `$keys` should be the result. The `$catalogue_html .= join(", ", $keys) . "\n";` is where you have to put computation.